# it is possible to download GitHub repository to my local computer

Tags: api, github, repository, github-api

hello friends i just started to use GitHub and i just want to know it is possible to download github repository to my local computer through by Using GitHub Api or Api libraries (ie. python library " pygithub3" for Github api)

Answer (score 2):

Using [`github3.py`](http://github3py.rtfd.org/) you can clone all of your repositories (including forks and private repositories) by doing:

```
import github3
import subprocess


g = github3.login('username', 'password')
for repo in g.iter_repos(type='all'):
    subprocess.call(['git', 'clone', repo.clone_url])
```

If you're looking to clone an arbitrary repository you can do this:

```
import github3
import subprocess


r = github3.repository('owner', 'repository_name')
subprocess.call(['git', 'clone', repo.clone_url])
```

pygithub3 has not been actively developed in over a year. I would advise not use it since it is unmaintained and missing a large number of the additions GitHub has made to their API since then.

Comment: ok then can you please suggest me another python library for GitHub Api??? and thank you for answer :)

Comment: @user3321823 I suggested github3.py in my example.

Comment: Yes, but in your answer you wrote that pygithub3 not been actively developed that's why i'm enquiring  which one is better python library then pygithub3 ? please suggest which one you prefer.

Comment: pygithub3 is not github3.py. They are vastly different libraries. I prefer github3.py because I wrote it

Comment: OK thank you  Mr. Cordasco for your replay I tried your suggested example but I'm getting error -->  The requested URL returned error: 403 while accessing https://api.github.com/users/myusername/repos/info/refs.

Comment: Do you have `github3.py` installed?

Comment: Yes and also installed dependencies 1) requests and 2)uritemplate.py

Comment: Neither of those examples should return that error. You can try replacing `clone_url` for `git_url`, but that would indicate you had an issue with the git clone command.

Comment: it is possible to talk through emails ??,because i have lot of things to ask and here is not right place where i able to ask all the questions...

Comment: My email address is on my GitHub profile. Feel free to send me questions directly. There's also a tag on here for github3.py I'm not the only one who answers questions there

Comment: ok thanx  I tried your both example but still it's giving me same Error i mentioned above and I tried your  second example to copy arbitrary repository with only "subprocess.call(['git', 'clone', repo.clone_url])" and it works so I confused that why i need github3 in that example ??

Comment: Open a new question with the proper tag or email me.

Answer (score 0):

As illustrated in [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/jharjono/1159239), the simplest solution is simply to call git clone.

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python
# Script to clone all the github repos that a user is watching
import requests
import json
import subprocess

# Grab all the URLs of the watched repo
user = 'jharjono'
r = requests.get("http://github.com/api/users/%s/subscriptions" % (user))
repos = json.loads(r.content)
urls = [repo['url'] for repo in repos['repositories']]

# Clone them all
for url in urls:
    cmd = 'git clone ' + url
    pipe = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True)
    pipe.wait()

print "Finished cloning %d watched repos!" % (len(urls))
```

[This gist](https://gist.github.com/decause/5777114#file-list-all-repos-py), which uses **[pygithub3](http://pygithub3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)**, will call git clone on the repos it finds:

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python

import pygithub3

gh = None


def gather_clone_urls(organization, no_forks=True):
    all_repos = gh.repos.list(user=organization).all()
    for repo in all_repos:

        # Don't print the urls for repos that are forks.
        if no_forks and repo.fork:
            continue

        yield repo.clone_url


if __name__ == '__main__':
    gh = pygithub3.Github()

    clone_urls = gather_clone_urls("gittip")
    for url in clone_urls:
        print url
```

Comment: I don't understand how showing a usage of Version 2 of the GitHub API is helpful. That version is deprecated and completely irrelevant.

Comment: @sigmavirus24 I have edited the answer to use V3 api. The general idea remains the same.

Comment: Your API url in the first example is still very wrong.